# .htaccess / PHP controlled distribution of a Chrome Extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

This seems very vague, but I don't know how to go about this! I have a Chrome Extension that I want to try to manage the distribution of! I do not want the user to be able to directly download the extension (to prevent them from distributing it), but when you click the link to the file, like with all Chrome Extensions it will ask if you want to install it!

Sorry for the vague question :/.

Answer (score 3):

To be installed - an extension needs to be downloaded first, and you cannot do anything with this.

KO to the rescue.